# I am using TexShop 4.27. I have question regarding page numbers on the first page of indexes

Tags: scrbook, imakeidx

I am using document class scrbook. I have four indexes in my book. I want Indexes to appear in the TOC. So I used \chapter command for this. But then I get page number on the first page of each index, which I don't want. How do I avoid this number?

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,english]{scrbook}

\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{empty}

\setkomafont{subsection}{\Large\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=authors,title=Index of Authors]
\makeindex[name=texts,title=Index of Texts]
\makeindex[name=words,columns=3,title=Index of Words]
\makeindex[name=genres,title=Index of Genres]

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\textbf{Milking the Wish-fulfilling Cow}}
\fancyhead[CO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{}
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fileds

\begin{document}

\chapter{Indexes}
\printindex[genres]
\thispagestyle{empty}
\printindex[authors]
\thispagestyle{empty}
\printindex[texts]
\thispagestyle{empty}
\printindex[words]
\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the page style of the first index page to `empty` you can use

```latex
\indexsetup{firstpagestyle=empty}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
%\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}% does not have an affect if fancyhdr is used
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{empty}

\setkomafont{subsection}{\Large\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\usepackage{fontspec}% <- changed
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\indexsetup{firstpagestyle=empty}% <=== first page of an index should use page style empty
\makeindex[name=authors,title=Index of Authors]
\makeindex[name=texts,title=Index of Texts]
\makeindex[name=words,columns=3,title=Index of Words]
\makeindex[name=genres,title=Index of Genres]

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\textbf{Milking the Wish-fulfilling Cow}}
\fancyhead[CO]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}% added
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum[1-20]% dummy text to get some pages in the chapter
\section{Bar}
\lipsum[21-30]% dummy text to get some pages in the section

% dummy index entries:
\index[authors]{Author}
\index[texts]{Text}
\index[words]{Word}
\index[genres]{Genre}

\chapter{Indexes}
\printindex[genres]
\lipsum% dummy text to get some pages in the index
\printindex[authors]
\lipsum% dummy text to get some pages in the index
\printindex[texts]
\lipsum% dummy text to get some pages in the index
\printindex[words]
\lipsum% dummy text to get some pages in the index
\end{document}
```

But I would suggest to use KOMA-Script package `scrlayer-scrheadings` with a KOMA-Script class:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{}
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{empty}

\setkomafont{subsection}{\Large\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\usepackage{fontspec}% <- changed
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\indexsetup{firstpagestyle=empty}% <=== first page of an index should use page style empty
\makeindex[name=authors,title=Index of Authors]
\makeindex[name=texts,title=Index of Texts]
\makeindex[name=words,columns=3,title=Index of Words]
\makeindex[name=genres,title=Index of Genres]

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\automark{chapter}
\automark*{section}
\clearmainofpairofpagestyles % clear all header and footer fields for scrheadings
\ohead{\pagemark}
\cehead{\textbf{Milking the Wish-fulfilling Cow}}
\cohead{\leftmark}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum[1-20]% dummy text to get some pages in the chapter
\section{Bar}
\lipsum[21-30]% dummy text to get some pages in the section

% dummy index entries:
\index[authors]{Author}
\index[texts]{Text}
\index[words]{Word}
\index[genres]{Genre}

\chapter{Indexes}
\printindex[genres]
\lipsum% dummy text to get some pages in the index
\printindex[authors]
\lipsum% dummy text to get some pages in the index
\printindex[texts]
\lipsum% dummy text to get some pages in the index
\printindex[words]
\lipsum% dummy text to get some pages in the index
\end{document}
```

But you could also redefine the `plain` style to be empty:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{}

\setkomafont{subsection}{\Large\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\usepackage{fontspec}% <- changed
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=authors,title=Index of Authors]
\makeindex[name=texts,title=Index of Texts]
\makeindex[name=words,columns=3,title=Index of Words]
\makeindex[name=genres,title=Index of Genres]

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\automark{chapter}
\automark*{section}
\clearpairofpagestyles % clear all header and footer fields for scrheadings and plain
\ohead{\pagemark}
\cehead{\textbf{Milking the Wish-fulfilling Cow}}
\cohead{\leftmark}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum[1-20]% dummy text to get some pages in the chapter
\section{Bar}
\lipsum[21-30]% dummy text to get some pages in the section

% dummy index entries:
\index[authors]{Author}
\index[texts]{Text}
\index[words]{Word}
\index[genres]{Genre}

\chapter{Indexes}
\printindex[genres]
\lipsum% dummy text to get some pages in the index
\printindex[authors]
\lipsum% dummy text to get some pages in the index
\printindex[texts]
\lipsum% dummy text to get some pages in the index
\printindex[words]
\lipsum% dummy text to get some pages in the index
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked!

Comment: You're welcome. If you like the answer, you can upvote it. If the answer solves your issue, can accept it.